How can I automatically increment the version of my local NuGet (Baget) package in my .csproj file
We use local NuGet (BaGet) to store our custom packages. We assign a new version number for each update we make. I am sharing code snipped from my .csproj file in the below:
  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netstandard2.0</TargetFramework>
    <RootNamespace>Macha.Abp.Common</RootNamespace>
    <GeneratePackageOnBuild>True</GeneratePackageOnBuild>
    <PackageReadmeFile>README.md</PackageReadmeFile>
    <Version>5.3.3.23</Version>
  </PropertyGroup>

Every single time my package is updated, I must update the version number (5.3.3.23, 5.3.3.24 , 5.3.3.25, 5.3.3.26, and so on). 5.3.3 is my framework version. By the way, we are using ABP Framework. I would like to read this version number from assemby like this:
<Version>typeof(AbpModule).Assembly.GetFileVersion()+"23"</Version>, but I don't know how can I write this code.
If you have any other suggestions, I would be happy to hear them.

How does your version number generator know your app is updated? I would say to create an exe that updates the csproj file as a build event, perhaps with some incrementing number or something based on date.. but you'll need to decide if there is a more complex mechanic such as "the last modified date of the readme file has changed, increase the 23 to 24 on the end of the version" - you're a software engineer; you can make software do anything :D

If this version you should be updated during the building, you could write a powsershell script and call it to update this version at building time.
